# hierarchical data template class for treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'd like to implement in my project a hierarchical data template for my treeviews.
The structure should look like that:

```
- ManagedItems (RootItem)
     - Department 1
         -Client 1
             - Feature 1
             - Feature 2
         -Client 2
             - Feature 1
     - Department 2
             - Department 4
                     - Department 5
                            -Client 4
                                   - Feature 1
     - Department 3
         -Client 3
             - Feature 1
             - Feature 2
             - Feature 3


//Current class for datatype
public class Entries
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }

    // ?? How to implement a drive array and a feature array which will be displayed correctly in the treeview?

    public ObservableCollection<Entries> Children { get; set; }
}
```

It's in C# and WPF (.NET 4.0).
Some ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wire-frame for your model:

```
class ManagedItems {
   IList<Department> Departments // TreeView.ItemsSource
}
class Department {// HierDT
   IList<object> Children // HierDT.ItemsSource; (can either be Department or Client)
}
class Client {// HierDT
   IList<Feature> Features // HierDT.ItemsSource
}
class Feature { } // normal DataTemplate
```

Define `Department` and `Client` `HierDTs` and `Feature` `DataTemplate` in `TreeView.Resources`.

Note `Department.Children` are `objects`. This is OK, because when WPF "sees" a `Client`, it will "inflate" to the appropriate `HierDT` (as well as when it "sees" a `Department`, it will inflate to  `Department`'s defined `HierDT`).

Comment: this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) is the de facto best example for WPF TreeView on the web. if you haven't heard of MVVM, you may want to look at some examples of it as well.