# Complex (?) TreeView Structure - HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

According to thread (WPF, C#) [hierarchicalDataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9707835/1011394)

I didn't get it to work.
My problem is just that a treeviewitem of class department can be added to another department treeeviewitem and so on... For now it's just possible to implement a 1-level department structure.

```
- Department 2
         - Department 4
                 - Department 5
                        -Client 4
                               - Feature 1
```

I'm very grateful for some new help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?
Give all the items ( Department, Client and maybe Feature) an `ObservableCollection<object>` property and name it Children
Also add a `String Name` property in every item.

You can add anything to Children like Department or Client or whatever.
This is the xaml:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Example classes:

```
public class Department
{
  public ObservableCollection<Object> Children { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
  public ObservableCollection<Object> Children { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I think that's exactly what I want to do.
Quite simple and fast. I've added to your solution a constructor for all the classes to initialise the collections. For now, in my test scenario, it works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user1011394 Should have thought of this sooner but it would be more elegant if the name and children properties where in an abstract class afcourse. Good luck anyway:)